# Python method or class to compare two video files?

Tags: python, file, compare

I'm trying to write a program to compare files and show the duplicates in python. Anyone know any good functions or methods related to this? I am sorta lost...

Comment: Are you looking to compare the images or the raw bytes? (That is, should two video files that are essentially the same video but have different resolution/quality/whatnot match or not?)

Comment: what ever is easier to implement.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking for exact duplicates, do an [MD5 hash](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) on both and see if they match:

```
import hashlib

file1 = open('file1.avi', 'r').read()
file2 = open('file2.avi', 'r').read()

if hashlib.sha512(file1).hexdigest() == hashlib.sha512(file2).hexdigest():
  print 'They are the same'
else:
  print 'They are different'
```

If not, I'd try [OpenCV's Python Bindings](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html) and check if they match up frame by frame.

Comment: Be aware that MD5 has been broken; while it is sufficient for comparing general file uniqueness, it would be possible for an attacker to create a 'fake match'.

Comment: I doubt you would get a collision by comparing video files. But if you insist, I'll use something a bit better ;)

Comment: It's easier to directly use [hashlib.file_digest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#file-hashing).

Answer (score 1):

I would use os.walk to go through the file tree.

For each file, I would store the absolutepath+filename, indexed by file size and signature (first 16 bytes? Hash of first 512 bytes? Hash on full file?).

When finished, you end up with a dict of file sizes; for each size, a dict of file signatures; for each signature, a list of all files sharing that signature. If your file signature is not based on the full file, or has significant chance of collisions, you can then do a more in-depth comparison of just those colliding files.

Answer (score 0):

I would first start out comparing filenames and filesizes. If you find a match, you could then loop through the bytes of the file to compare them, although this is probably pretty intensive.

I do not know of a library that can do this in python.